# Select Where And Where Command in SQLite DataBase(Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

This code works:

```
     Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+dbHelper.TABLE_NAME+" where `" +
            dbHelper.MyShifts_Month + "`=" + month ,null);
```

And this doesn't:

```
 Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+dbHelper.TABLE_NAME+" where `" +
            dbHelper.MyShifts_Month + "`=" + month + " and " + dbHelper.MyShifts_year + "`=" + year,null);
```

How should I write the "AND" correctly in order to make it work?

Comment: do you mean and? can you edit your post with exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that a single quote is missing, it should be " and `"